# How create a web service and use it in smart phone application?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-phone, smartphone

I am planning to develop a mobile application in Windows phone 8 (not planning, application side is almost completed except this database connection part). But in my application I need a Database support. So I bought a domain and server space and created the Database there. But I don't know how to create a web-service communication between the smartphone and the server. I am not talking about the code to communicate the web-service. I mean how can I implement a web-service communication between my application and server. I Googled, but I did not get any clear concept.

I have database in my server. While Googling I saw many notes that creating web-service in visual studio and then right click the application and add the web-service using "Add service reference" option. But I am not actually planing to do like this. I want to make my web-service communication through HttpWebrequest from my code and need to get the result as JSON or XML format.

I know how to call web-service URL from application and get response in my application. But the thing I don't know is the server part. About how create and deploy a web-service in server and create a service URL for my application to consume.

While working in some companies, the server side people provide the web-service URL, and we smartphone developers just use this URL in our application, But not aware about how they implemented in server. So am only aware about how use web-service in phone side.

Answer (score 0):

i have been working on Json web Services for windows phone, so probably u should see the example below (how to use json web services to get the data from server)

```
Uri uri = new Uri("localhost:2345/API/GetUsers");
WebClient wbclient = new WebClient(); 
wbclient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
wbclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, eargs) =>
    {
      if (eargs.Error == null)
      {
        var UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(e.Result);
        // bind users to ur itemsControl
      }
      else
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("failed !"));

    };
```

**at server side**

```
public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {
            var Users= // queries to ur db to fetch the data
            return Json(Users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: yes Thanks, me too have been working in this. I know how to use json/rest web services to get the data from server. But my problem is server part. Now I want to handle both the server and the client( smartphone). But I am not aware about how to create and implement service in server and provide the "localhost:2345/API/GetUsers"(example) to my application to use.